# Javascript prototype.constructor not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am new to `Javascript` `Object Oriented Programming`. I need to write a `JS` `class`, which can be `inherited`. The complete class can be `inherited`. As well as whenever the `document` is `ready`, it gets called.

I am trying in this following way:

```
alert('reached');
var Hello = new VeerWidget();

function VeerWidget(){}

VeerWidget.prototype.constructor = function()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('called');
    });
}
```

I have the above code in `xyz.js`

What I am expecting is: as soon as the page loads, `popup` with *reached* is called followed by `popup` with *called*.

But this is not working. `popup` with *reached* is called. However *called* is not called.

However when I am trying this way:

```
alert('reached');
var Hello = new VeerWidget();

function VeerWidget()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('called');
    });
}
```

Everything goes fine. But I need to inherit `VeerWidget`. How to do this.?

Comment: study up on javascript variable "hoisting" if you want to learn why it doesnt work like you expect.

Comment: Change the order. You are initiating `Hello` and _then_ setting the constructor. First define everything you need to define on VeerWidget and _then_ make instances

Comment: @rambocoder: The reason why it doesn't work has nothing to do with hoisting.

Comment: @FelixKling: True, but the advice to look it up is good because it is the reason for the *second* example to work :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
VeerWidget.prototype.constructor = function()
```

What it does is set a value to a property that is visible to all instances.

The constructor of the instances is actually the VeerWidget function and that doesn't change no matter what you do, so your code should be like this:

```
alert('reached');
var Hello = new VeerWidget();

function VeerWidget(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('called');
    });
}
```

As for inheritance, i'm not entirely sure what you're after, but it could look like this:

```
function InheritingWidget() {
    VeerWidget.call(this);
}

InheritingWidget.prototype = Object.create(VeerWidget.prototype);
InheritingWidget.prototype.constructor = InheritingWidget;

var inheritingHello = new InheritingWidget();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply execute prototype's constructor function by adding this line at the end of your main constructor:

```
if(typeof this.__proto__.constructor === 'function') this.__proto__.constructor();
```

The final result would be:

```
VeerWidget.prototype.constructor = function(parent) {
    var message = parent.getMessage();
    $(document).ready(function(){
       alert(message);
    });
}

alert('reached');
var Hello = new VeerWidget();

function VeerWidget()
{
    if(typeof this.__proto__.constructor === 'function') this.__proto__.constructor();
}
```

---

**Note:** You may pass the parent function to access it's methods like this:

```
VeerWidget.prototype.constructor = function(parent) {
    var message = parent.getMessage();
    $(document).ready(function(){
       alert(message);
    });
}

function VeerWidget()
{
    this.getMessage = function() {return 'called';};
    if(typeof this.__proto__.constructor === 'function') this.__proto__.constructor(this);
}
```